# How do you beat out campers on demolition?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-series

I really like playing Demolition on MW3 (or any COD game) but I have problems dealing with the campers that guard the bomb. I understand how they let you blow out a bomb and then they all just migrate over to the other and otherwise completely ruin your chance of planting. I'd like to know if anyone has any tactics or whatever to overcome the campers

Answer (score 7):

Camping is a pretty powerful strategy in CoD multiplayer, and it's not just a problem in Demolition, although it is arguably worse there than in most modes once you've taken out one bomb site.

The problem with breaking a solid camping strategy is that it generally only takes limited cooperation between a couple of players to set up a good camp, but it takes a significant amount of strategy by the other team in order to break it.  For this reason, Demolition is a frustrating gametype to play unless you've got a pretty solidly coordinated team.

Campers generally rely on a number of advantages:

- They tend to engage at a fixed distance, which means that by choosing the proper weapons, they can have a "natural" advantage at that range
- They can get and keep you in their sights faster than you can do the same to them
- The game is focused on twitch/reflexes moreso than strategy
- Enemies generally come from a single direction or a limited number of directions
- Your team arrives sporadically
- The game rewards getting many kills by making it *easier* on the camping side

To break a solid camp, you're going to have to tilt all of these advantages in your favor.

Here's a point by point "sample" strategy:

- Have a diverse set of loadouts, and pick based on the area you're engaging in.  For instance, don't bring an assault rifle to a close quarters fight - a shotgun kills far, far quicker at short range, and you'll be at a disadvantage.
- Approach from an angle where you've got an aiming advantage.  For instance, can you approach where your body is more or less covered by boxes or a low wall?  This gives you an advantage when aiming, especially if they're in the open.
- Give yourself more time to aim and fire.  Campers are going to be staring at one or two locations, waiting for you to emerge.  Approach from the side, and you've got a couple of seconds while they retarget, whereas you generally know where they're going to be already.  Knowing how to arc and bounce your tac grenades can also come in handy.
- Try to flank and come from multiple directions.  Depending on the level of coordination the enemy team is demonstrating, they may or may not be protecting alternate/longer routes from your spawn to the objective.  You can exploit this faster with creative use of tac inserts.
- Time your assaults with other teammates.  There's an urge among CoD players to run right from the spawn to the action as fast as possible - try to hang back at the spawn for a few seconds (and encourage others to do the same) so that you arrive as a group.  This way, there are multiple targets, and multiple times the firepower and tac/lethal grenades hitting the camp zone at the same time.
- Pack a class that can deal with killstreak rewards,and focus on taking them out quickly.  The EMP especially is powerful against campers - it kills heartbeat sensors, almost all killstreak rewards, and disables the radar for 60 seconds after use.  However, having a launcher secondary means that you can usually destroy an air support killstreak in a single life, which can preserve multiple friendly lives.

There are many ways to break a camp, although the better the people are at camping a given location, and the more coordinated their team is, the harder it will be.  Focus on **coordination** and don't forget to **consume your whole loadout** - bullets in your primary weapon are most people's only thought when trying to get a kill, but there is significant strategy in secondary weapons and loadout choices.

Answer (score 3):

Generally what I do, is get all explosived up, and wait for one team member. Grab as many explosives as you can, sticky's, crossbow and the like. Once you have a team member going towards the enemies camping site, try to stick as much as you can even if it gets you killed. The enemies will spawn further away and you can get back about when they do. If your team member is any good at all he would have taken advantage of the short hiccup in the enemies camping, and if your lucky another team member will have arrived. Then when you get there, it can be you 3 camping. All you need is a short gap, and if you waited for a team member, and gave them that gap it is possible. (I would suggest changing classes after you pretty much suicide bomb their 'camp'.)

Approach from the least open areas as most of the campers will guard the open areas expecting a couple people to come from there. Camping is a very good strategy, and is often hard to break. Hope my strategy helps :)

My other strategy (takes some pretty good skill, if I haven't played for a while I generally can't do it. Get a sniper. Get a limited view of their 'camp' and have good cover. Pick them off, earning up killstreaks. Get the stealth bombers, the fire bomb thing, mortars, chopper, whatever. Anything with a wide range and explosive power will dominate their 'camp'.

Answer (score 1):

- Beat the stragglers and get air support.
- Flank or surprise your enemy.
  Campers on console have lag (since connection works in saying where you are and what you're doing.) e.g. If you jump around a corner they've been sitting for a while, you have the advantage in timing, and showing on their screen slightly later than you actually there (normally 0.6 of second host vs normal) and (possibly 0.2 of second normal vs normal).
- Using stuns and frags is a clear way to show you're coming, throwing them one way and running another works if they are resilient to its effects.

Finally, AND MOST IMPORTANT!!!...... A camper's biggest weakness is his urge to reload after every kill - sometimes using your team mate as bait and catching them on a reload is your only way.

Answer (score 0):

If I know where they may camp (bomb site etc.), and I see them hard camping, I switch to a class with recon and flash nades. I flash them and when they show up on the map, I can see exactly in which direction they are looking (you know they usually look straight in one direction...). Flash nades are better than stuns for recon, as they have a higher "radius of impact" (? don't really know how to say this lol), meaning that you can get flashed at a greater distance from the explosion. Even if the enemy isn't much disturbed by the tactical nade, you will see exactly where he is, and most importantly where he's looking at, so you can flank him.

When I am not using recon, I usually run stuns and a semtex. Throw your stun close enough to the enemy spot and if you get a hit marker, immediately throw your semtex, in the exact same direction as your stun. That's a 95% sure kill, as the enemy won't be able to run away, and because the two nades will end up at the same spot (remember that a flash will explode after a certain time, and the stun will explode when touching the ground).

Get those freaking campers !!!